# Update Value of all XML tags in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

Is there any way to replace the value of multiple occurrences of a tag in an xml in SQL Server?

I need to check for a specific tag (FirstName) and replace ALL of its values with another.

Here is my sample xml:

```
<Root>
  <Patient>
    <FirstName>Something</FirstName>
    <MiddleInitial>W</MiddleInitial>
    <LastName>West</LastName>
  </Patient>
  <Patient>
    <FirstName>Another</FirstName>
    <MiddleInitial>E</MiddleInitial>
    <LastName>East</LastName>
  </Patient>
</Root>
```

My desired output is:

```
<Root>
  <Patient>
    <FirstName>TEST</FirstName>
    <MiddleInitial>W</MiddleInitial>
    <LastName>West</LastName>
  </Patient>
  <Patient>
    <FirstName>TEST</FirstName>
    <MiddleInitial>E</MiddleInitial>
    <LastName>East</LastName>
  </Patient>
</Root>
```

I currently have this modify statement which will change the first occurrence but it ignores the next 'FirstName' tag that comes up:

```
SET @x.modify('
  replace value of
    (/Root/Patient/FirstName[1]/text())[1]
  with "TEST"
');
```

Which gives me this:

```
<Root>
  <Patient>
    <FirstName>TEST</FirstName>
    <MiddleInitial>W</MiddleInitial>
    <LastName>West</LastName>
  </Patient>
  <Patient>
    <FirstName>Another</FirstName>
    <MiddleInitial>E</MiddleInitial>
    <LastName>East</LastName>
  </Patient>
</Root>
```

I tried throwing this into a while loop, to execute when the path exists but it looks like I just created an infinite loop:

```
WHILE @x.exist('(/Root/Patient/FirstName[1]/text())[1]') = 1
```

Any thoughts on getting around this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better way but one approach would be

```
WHILE @x.exist('(/Root/Patient/FirstName[text() != "TEST"])') = 1
SET @x.modify('
  replace value of
     (/Root/Patient/FirstName[text() != "TEST"][1]/text())[1]
  with "TEST"
');
```

Comment: Thank you Martin, That did exactly what I needed!